# How are optional arguments in the middle of a function signature implemented?

Tags: javascript

How is this implemented in JavaScript?

```
function myFunc(arg1, [optionsObject,] callback)
```

If the `optionsObject` is missing, the callback will be in the second position instead of the third position. How does the function notice this situation and handle it appropriately?

Comment: Something like `typeof secondArgument`, which is either `"function"` or `"object"`, maybe? Or `arguments.length` which is either `2` or `3`.

Answer (score 3):

It's not JS that's doing this but the function itself, `myFunc` in your case. What's usually done is to take `arguments` (which is an array-like structure containing your arguments) and determine what the last item is. If it's a function, pop it off and take it as a callback. What remains are just plain arguments.

Here's sample code:

```
function myFunc(){
  // arguments is usually turned into an array to access array methods
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);

  // Check the type of the last item
  var hasCallback = typeof args[args.length - 1] === 'function';

  // If the last item is a function, it's probably a callback. Pop it off.
  var callback = hasCallback ? args.pop() : function(){};

  // By now, args is your argument list and callback is a function that either
  // does something or is a noop.
}
```